# llblgen Pro SELECT TOP (n) equivalent query

Tags: llblgenpro

Is it possible to perform a select top (n) query in llblgen pro?...not LINQ. If so, how can I achieve that using the SelfServicing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the GelMulti overloads that accepts the maxItemsToReturn parameter:

```
int itemsToReturn = 10;    
OrderCollection orders = new OrderCollection();
orders.GetMulti(null, itemsToReturn);
```

This is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT TOP(@p2) [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerId], ... 
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]  
Parameter: @p2 : Int64. Length: 0. Precision: 0. Scale: 0. Direction: Input. Value: 10.
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that you can add a diagnostic switch to your app.config or web.config to see in the output window the generated sql.  Here is a Sql 2008 example - <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="SqlServerDQE" value="4" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>